# Opening a rowset for "Sheet1$" failed

Tags: excel

I am using SSIS to export an Excel 2007 file to a SQL table. When I execute my package locally it works; however, on the server I get the following error:

> Data Flow Task:Error: Excel Source failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC02020E8.
>
> Data Flow Task:Error: Opening a rowset for "Sheet$" failed. Check that the object exists in the database.
>
> Data Flow Task:Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.

I have tried the following, with no success:

- changing the sheet name to just A
- Installing the Ace 12.0 driver
- Converted my Excel file to a flat file (that takes a long time, so the app times out)

Comment: Are you doing it all locally? If your excel sheet is saved on your desktop c:\user\documents and you pass a command to your sql server, it will look to its own c:\user\documents folder - and find nothing.

Comment: It can also be a driver issue. Does your SQL server have the Access 2010 drivers (or an installation of MS Office?)

Comment: If it's not those, you can try connecting your excel sheet as a Server object, and inserting that way.

Comment: oh, and make sure that your sql service accounts have access to the folder where you've saved the excel sheet.

Comment: Are you running the package the same way locally and on the server? If not (for instance, if you're using the Execute Package app on the server, and running from within SQL Server Data Tools locally), try running the package the same way in both environments. Depending on the version of SSIS, you may need to run the package in 32-bit mode.

Comment: Running the package in 32 bit mode did not work.I used a stored procedure to call and execute the package .The following is the error i got                                                                                                         Msg 27146, Level 16, State 1, Procedure create_execution, Line 183
Cannot access the package or the package does not exist. Verify that the package exists and that the user has permissions to it.

Comment: After calling the excel page as SELECT * FROM [Sheet$] from the data flow , i saved my ssis package. Then , i deployed my package on a server. The following is the error i am getting.                                      Data Flow Task:Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft Access Database Engine"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Unexpected error from external database driver (1).".

Comment: I have also checked my tempdb to see if there is memory issue ...

Comment: I had the same problem. I had multiple files with supposedly the same name for a spreadsheet (which was "Sheet1" as a default). All files except for one were OK. It turned out the someone changed the name and inserted the space and made it "Sheet 1" instead. Please open your Excel file and check for the actual name of the spreadsheet. It should be "Sheet" not default "Sheet1".